# Is it safe to ignore the result of DispEventUnadvise?

Tags: c++, com, atl

I'm writing a BHO using ATL and I'm using `DispEventUnadvise` as part of my `SetSite` function to disconnect from Internet Explorer.

This is my code:

```
STDMETHODIMP FooBho::SetSite(IUnknown* site)
{
    if (site != nullptr)
    {
        if( this->webBrowser != nullptr )
        {
            this->webBrowser.Release();
        }
        // Cache the pointer to IWebBrowser2.
        HRESULT hr = site->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**) &this->webBrowser);
        ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(hr);

        // Register event-handler.
        hr = DispEventAdvise(this->webBrowser);
        ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(hr);

        this->isAdvised = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Release cached pointers and other resources here.
        if( this->isAdvised )
        {
            HRESULT hr = DispEventUnadvise( this->webBrowser );
            ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(hr); // This assertion often fails when hr == 0x80040200 
            this->isAdvised = false;
        }

        this->webBrowser.Release();
    }

    // Return the base class implementation
    return IObjectWithSiteImpl<FooBho>::SetSite(site);
}
```

Many times `DispEventUnadvise` returns`0x80040200` which corresponds to a number of different HRESULTs, but I think it's corresponding to `EVENT_E_FIRST` but I'm not sure, the documentation for `DispEventUnadvise` doesn't document its error codes.

The failing assert in `ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED` causes my BHO to crash, so I need to remove it, but is it safe to completely disregard the return value from `DispEventUnadvise` or should I check for `0x80040200` and otherwise still call `ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED`?

#### Update

This is my class' header, it includes the Sink Map:

```
// FooBho.h : Declaration of the CFooBho

#pragma once
#include "resource.h"       // main symbols

#include <ShlGuid.h> // IID_IWebBrowser2, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, etc.
#include <exdispid.h> // DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE, etc.
#include <MsHTML.h>

#include "Bho_i.h"

using namespace ATL;

const int DispatchInterface1 = 1;

class ATL_NO_VTABLE FooBho :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<FooBho, &CLSID_FooBho>,
    public IObjectWithSiteImpl<FooBho>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IFooBho, &IID_IFooBho, &LIBID_BhoLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>,
    public IDispEventImpl<DispatchInterface1, FooBho, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 1>
{
private:

    CComPtr<IWebBrowser2> webBrowser;
    bool                  isAdvised;

public:
    FooBho()
    {
    }

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_FOOBHO)

DECLARE_NOT_AGGREGATABLE(FooBho)

BEGIN_COM_MAP(FooBho)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IFooBho)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IObjectWithSite)
END_COM_MAP()

    STDMETHOD(SetSite)(IUnknown *site) override;

    DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

    HRESULT FinalConstruct()
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    void FinalRelease()
    {
    }

#pragma region DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2

    BEGIN_SINK_MAP(FooBho)
        SINK_ENTRY_EX(DispatchInterface1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE, OnDocumentComplete)
    END_SINK_MAP()

    void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDocumentComplete(IDispatch* dispatch, VARIANT* uri);

#pragma endregion

private:

    long RemoveImages(IHTMLDocument2* document);

};

OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(__uuidof(FooBho), FooBho)
```

Comment: Warning you ahead of time it has been *forever* since I've done this, as I recall, if you already have `this->webBrowser` attached to an interface when `SetSite` is invoked, you need to release it first. You may want to double-check and act accordingly. ATL smart pointers sometimes... aren't. Don't just blast over your `webBroweser` member with a fresh QI, check it first, and if its non-null, `.Release()` it.

Comment: You need to assert() it so you can find a bug in your code.  That's all.

Answer (score 3):

The error code stands for `CONNECT_E_NOCONNECTION`, which is presumably returned by internal [`IConnectionPointContainer::FindConnectionPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call. That is, there is no connection point, something is wrong with the sink map, which you did not include.

There are other things wrong in your code snippet. Use of `ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED` is incorrect. It throws exception which you are supposed to catch before returning from COM method.

```
STDMETHODIMP FooBho::SetSite(IUnknown* site)
{
  _ATLTRY
  {
    // ...
    ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(...);
    // ...
  }
  _ATLCATCH(Exception)
  {
    return Exception;
  }
  return S_OK; 
}
```

Error code safe to ignore would be code telling "you were not advised to `Unadvise`".

Comment: The code is about right, no apparent differences from similar non-BHO I have working. I can only think of unadvising too late when browser itself is at some late destruction stage. Remember that connection point container holds a reference to your object. If ignoring the error leads to proper destruction/release of your object then you're fine and browser supposedly flushed the connection point on its own.

Comment: I noticed it only happens when I'm closing IE, it doesn't happen during otherwise normal operation of IE.

Comment: It tells for scenario that you're trying to disconnect "too late" when the host is already broken into pieces on destruction way. Note that connection on connection point is typically a circular reference. Browser might be interested in flushing connection point to force disconnection and avoid memory leaks.

Comment: So it's safe to ignore that specific HRESULT in that case?

Comment: I suppose yes, I would just double check memory leaks (specifically if you have your BHO refcount destroyed on zero external references).

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable about passing the error code, you might want to handle some earlier event from the browser (like window is closed etc.) and unadvise then, without waiting when "it's too late".

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide second parameter to *DispEventUnadvise* pointing to uuid of 'Events' interface, like

```
HRESULT hr = DispEventUnadvise(this->webBrowser, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2);
```

This way I solved the same problem (with same error code) in CANoe application